# ¿Es posible hacer un login desde Postman usando Spring?

Tags: spring-boot, spring, postman

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en Spring y he creado un API CRUD de usuarios usando Spring, MySQL y Postman, con sus respectivas excepciones.

Mi pregunta es si es posible crear un login desde el Postman.

Por ejemplo un método que pueda llamar desde Postman y pasarle usuario y contraseña y que me retorne si el login es correcto o no, con los datos obtenidos de la base de datos.

Comment: depende el tipo de api, crud no es un tipo de api.

Comment: Todavia me confundo mucho con los terminos, pero basicamente mi proyecto es un CRUD de usuarios, con el nickname, contraseña y email